# If statement that only performs action when selection is within a specific column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to finish this macro that will open another workbook, copy, and paste the selected cells into the other workbook. I want to do this only when the selection is in column A and only when the selection contains data.

The if the selection contains data part is easy, however how can I make a statement that says if selection is not within column A, then `MsgBox("Please select data")`?

Here is the if statement so far, it still needs the part mentioned directly above.

```
'Warns if no QN#s are selected
If Selection = "" Then
MsgBox ("Please Select Your QN#s Before Running This Macro")
Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Is the selection a single cell?

Comment: The selection could be multiple cells. I figured out the part I questioned, however now I am actually having problems with it recognizing if a multiple selection is empty (""). Is there a way to make it recognize this fact so that if someone highlights multiple cells in column A that are blank, it will run the msgbox?

Comment: What does mean *only when selection has data*? Selection can span multiple columns - so, do you need strict one column or it's allowed to have several columns, but there must be intersection with column `A`?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for recognizing if the cells are within a certain column.

```
If Not Intersect(Selection, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
'Proceed
Else
MsgBox ("Please Select Your QN#s Before Running This Macro")
Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a Worksheet_SelectionChange?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column <> 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please Select Your QN#s Before Running This Macro", vbOKOnly, "Data Selection"
    Else
        RunMacro
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern of codes. This is just dealing with the selection and not detecting changes.

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As String
a = Selection.Row
b = Selection.Rows.Count - 1
c = "A" & a & ":" & "A" & a + b
If ((Selection.Column = 1) And (WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(c)) > 0)) Then

MsgBox "ready to go"

End If
```

In the above code the hidden rows with data will be considered.
Merged cells are considered as one cell with value and others are blanks( example: When you have merged A2:A5, then you have 3 blank cells)